# Is there a way to have FtpWebRequest/FtpWebResponse with SSH.NET dll?

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, ftpwebrequest, ssh.net

I have some code for downloading and uploading files with `FtpWebRequest` and `FtpWebResponse`.

I need to modify all to have SFTP instead of FTP.

Is there a way to have `FtpWebResponse` with SSH.NET libraries?

With this solution, I won't be forced to rework all the code, just to modify the connection to get a `FtpWebRequest`/`FtpWebResponse` with SFTP.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible.

There's no way to make `FtpWebRequest` use SSH/SFTP.

---

If you need an uniform interface that works across protocols, you need to use yet another library. The SSH.NET supports SSH/SFTP only.

For example [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) supports FTP, FTPS, FTPES, SFTP, SCP,
WebDAV, WebDAVS and S3 over the same interface.

Though it is not a native .NET assembly. It's rather a thin wrapper over
a console application.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP).*